# Display a level three groupby/sum from a SPARQL query as rows and columns and filter on years

Tags: group-by, sum, sparql, rdf, transpose

I have some RDF data which I simplified with the below table.

| Subject | StartDate | EndDate | Location | Technology | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subject1 | 1-1-2005 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneA | TechnologyA | 100 |
| Subject2 | 1-1-2007 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneB | TechnologyA | 50 |
| Subject3 | 1-1-2009 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneA | TechnologyB | 80 |
| Subject4 | 1-1-2011 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneB | TechnologyB | 100 |
| Subject5 | 1-1-2007 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneA | TechnologyA | 20 |
| Subject6 | 1-1-2009 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneB | TechnologyA | 10 |
| Subject7 | 1-1-2011 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneA | TechnologyB | 60 |
| Subject8 | 1-1-2013 | 1-1-2025 | ZoneB | TechnologyB | 70 |

I want to write a SPARQL query that does the following:

- Groupby the Location, Technology and the Year (in which the Subjects exists), and sum the Value
- The Year in which the subject exists is determined from the StartDate and EndDate
- The Location and Technology must be presented as rows and the year as columns.

**Expected Output:**

| Location | Technology | 2005 | 2006 | 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZoneA | TechnologyA | 100 | 100 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 | 120 |
| ZoneA | TechnologyB | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 80 | 80 | 140 | 140 | 140 | 140 | 140 |
| ZoneB | TechnologyA | 0 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 | 60 |
| ZoneB | TechnologyB | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 100 | 170 | 170 | 170 |

I know that SPARQL does not support displaying data directly in a tabular format like a spreadsheet, but I am trying to avoid any necessary post-processing in e.g. python as much as possible. I want to export the expected output above as a csv file.

I really have no idea how to do this with SPARQL. I have done some simple groupby/sum queries and separately also managed to filter on years based on a StartDate and EndDate, but I really don't have a clue how to do the combined set of this.

Can someone please help me out with this one?

Comment: it is not possible in SPARQL to "explode" a range of numbers as you want with a given range of start and end date. It is also not possible to generate columns resp. transpose based on values. Long story short, if you a) know the range of years in your dataset and b) manually create (aka select the appropriate variable binding) those columns for each year in the projection part then it might be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your message. a.) I  actually do know the years for which I want to do the groupby (let's say 2005 to 2015) and b.) I can create them manually with something like this:
 SELECT ?Year
 
 BIND(xsd:gYear(?Year) AS ?Year)
   VALUES (?Year) { 
    (2005) (2006) (2007) (2008) (2009) (2010) (2011) (2012) (2013) (2014) (2015)
 }
 What would be the next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can try :

Let's take for example year 2005

- In the SELECT section you should write a SUM clause like this one

  `(SUM(?temp2005) AS ?2005)`
- In the WHERE section you should have

`BIND(IF(your condition,?theCapacity, 0) AS ?temp2005)`

---> So what this is actually doing is binding the variable containing the capacity to an another in a way that we can differentiate them for each year. It will then SUM all the variables associated to ``?temp2005 as a total which is in our case ?2005

- NOTE! That you will need to create manually a list of years with the VALUES clause in your WHERE section    `VALUES (?Year) {(2005) (2006) ... (2015) }

  ```
   PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/data#>
   PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

   SELECT ?location ?technology
   (SUM(?temp2005) AS ?2005)
   (SUM(?temp2006) AS ?2006)     
   (SUM(?temp2007) AS ?2007)
   (SUM(?temp2008) AS ?2008)
   (SUM(?temp2009) AS ?2009)
   (SUM(?temp2010) AS ?2010) 
   (SUM(?temp2011) AS ?2011)
   (SUM(?temp2012) AS ?2012)
   (SUM(?temp2013) AS ?2013)
   (SUM(?temp2014) AS ?2014)
   (SUM(?temp2015) AS ?2015)

  WHERE {
   ?subject a ex:Subject ;
         ex:startDate ?startDate;
         ex:endDate ?endDate;
         ex:location ?location ;
         ex:technology ?technology ;
         ex:value ?value .


   #Create our Year value   
   BIND(xsd:gYear(?Year) AS ?Year)
   VALUES (?Year) { 
   (2005) (2006) (2007) (2008) (2009) (2010) (2011) (2012) (2013) (2014) (2015)
    }

   #EXTRACT the year component from the date and bind them
    BIND(YEAR(?startDate) AS ?startYear)
    BIND(YEAR(?endDate) AS ?endYear)

    BIND(IF((?Year = 2005)&&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2005) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2006) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2006) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2007) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2007) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2008) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2008) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2009) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2009) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2010) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2010) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2011) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2011) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2012) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2012) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2013) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2013) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2014) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2014) .
    BIND(IF((?Year = 2015) &&((?Year>=?startYear) && (?Year<=?endYear)), ?value, 
    0) AS ?temp2015) .

    }

  GROUP BY ?location ?technology
  ORDER BY ?location ?technology
  ```

This how the ttl with your example looks like :

```
     @prefix ex: <http://example.com/data#> .
     @prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

     ex:Subject1 a ex:Subject ;
      ex:startDate "2005-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:location "ZoneA" ;
      ex:technology "TechnologyA" ;
      ex:value 100 .

     ex:Subject2 a ex:Subject ;
      ex:startDate "2007-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:location "ZoneB" ;
      ex:technology "TechnologyA" ;
      ex:value 50 .

     ex:Subject3 a ex:Subject ;
      ex:startDate "2009-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:location "ZoneA" ;
      ex:technology "TechnologyB" ;
      ex:value 80 .

     ex:Subject4 a ex:Subject ;
      ex:startDate "2011-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:location "ZoneB" ;
      ex:technology "TechnologyB" ;
      ex:value 100 .

     ex:Subject5 a ex:Subject ;
      ex:startDate "2007-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:location "ZoneA" ;
      ex:technology "TechnologyA" ;
      ex:value 20 .

     ex:Subject6 a ex:Subject ;
      ex:startDate "2009-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:location "ZoneB" ;
      ex:technology "TechnologyA" ;
      ex:value 10 .

     ex:Subject7 a ex:Subject ;
      ex:startDate "2011-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
      ex:location "ZoneA" ;
      ex:technology "TechnologyB" ;
      ex:value 60 .

    ex:Subject8 a ex:Subject ;
     ex:startDate "2013-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
     ex:endDate "2025-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
     ex:location "ZoneB" ;
     ex:technology "TechnologyB" ;
     ex:value 70 .
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nW1VJ.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that displays the output exactly as I need it! No need for further post-processing.